# Dead.letter email. Same domain name, different mail server

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have a server setup "myserver.com" and I'm trying to send emails from a PHP/Apache application on this server.  The host name is set to "myserver.com" and I can send emails to anyone outside of the myserver.com domain.

We are using a separate server/service and the problem is when I try to send emails to anyone on the myserver.com domain they don't get the email.

This also happens when I try to send via command line, I get a:
dead.letter... Saved message in /home/username/dead.letter

It seems that the MX record is being ignored... how can I force it to respect the MX record?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the first step is probably to consult a better source of information on IT problems. Like serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I force it to respect the MX record?

By setting a proper hostname.  If the server in question does not provide every single service for myserver.com, it needs to use a subdomain.